# How to add 24 hours to datetime object of javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding hours to Javascript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object)

I am having javascript datetime object .

I want to add 24 hours to that datetime

for ex.

if it is `2 dec 2012 3:30:00` => `3 dec 2012 3:29:00`

if it is `31 dec 2012 3:30:00` => `1 jan 2013 3:29:00`

etc

any suggestion ????

Comment: I haven't tried following code. But please believe in searching (a)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object

Comment: Doesn't `theDate.setDate(theDate.getDate()+1);` work?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
new Date(new Date(myStringDate).getTime() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000);
```

Comment: Why not just `var a = new Date(); a.setDate(a.getDate()+1);` ?

Comment: @Ian This is almost the same as [Glutamat posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13762964/1249581). Mine is yet another possible solution.

Comment: Oh of course they're both definitely solutions, I'm just wondering why a solution based on days wasn't proposed since that's what it's about. They all definitely work, I just thought the `.setDate` made since for moving by day.

Comment: Of course, there are many possible solutions,i like adjusting ms kind of more, so +1 on this  but since the OP asked for adding (24) Hours,  i just thought, why not giving him a solution where hours are used,

Comment: @ÆtherSurfer That makes no sense. It doesn't do that at all. It works exactly as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/T4Y49/

Comment: @Ian I see now.  I will delete my comment then.

Answer (score 40):

This would be one way

```
var myDate = new Date("2 dec 2012 3:30:00") // your date object
myDate.setHours(myDate.getHours() + 24)
console.log(myDate) //Mon Dec 03 2012 03:30:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)
```

- `Date.setHours` allows you to set the Hours of your Date Object
- `Date.getHours` retrieves them

In this Solution it simply gets the Hours from your Date Object adds 24 and writes them Back to your object.

Of course there are other Possible ways of achieving the same result e.g.

- Adjusting the milliseconds

  - `Date.getTime` gives you the milliseconds of the Object since midnight Jan 1, 1970
  - `Date.setTime` sets them

So adding `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` or `86400000` milliseconds to your Date Object will result in the same
See [VisioN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13762981/1487756)s Answer

- Adding a Day

  - `Date.getDate` gets the Date of the month of your `Date` Object
  - `Date.setDate` sets them

Increasing it by one, will again result in the same
As [Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317927/ian) mentioned in a comment

So its just depends on what feels the most understandable for you
And if you want to, give this w3schools [examples](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp) a look, to get a starting point of dealing with Dates