# How to create JavaScript Date object from yyyymmddhhiiss?

Tags: javascript, parsing, date, coffeescript

I have a string like so

```
date = '20121217030810'
```

And I need to create a `Date` object.

So far I'm trying this

```coffeescript
# coffeescript
if (m = /^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/.exec date)
  date = new Date("#{m[1]}-#{m[2]}-#{m[3]} #{m[4]}:#{m[5]}:#{m[6]}")
  #=> Mon Dec 17 2012 03:08:10 GMT-0600 (CST)
```

I just feel like there's a better way!

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like that is about the best you can do

Comment: See this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object

Comment: Not without using a library like moment.js - then you could do moment('20121217030810', 'YYYYMMDDHHmmss')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way than regex? No, maybe apart from manual string splitting.

But for the Date creation, you should use

```
new Date(Date.UTC(+m[1], m[2]-1, +m[3], +m[4], +m[5], +m[6]))
```

With some coffescript sugar, you also could do

```
m[2] -= 1
new Date(Date.UTC(m.slice(1)...))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Taking this one step farther, you can do this little handy trick in coffeescript: `new Date(Date.UTC(m.slice(1)...))`. If you update your answer, I will mark it as accepted ^.^