# How to add hours from 2 cells?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some google spreadsheet logbook where I store duration of some activities in hours format [[HH]:MM:SS]. The spreadsheet adds such cells with no issues. However when I try to add them via Google Script I get some garbage. What I found is that Date() object is implicitly created for such cells, but I cannot find API of that value type.

I know I can convert the data to "hour integers" by multiplying them by 24 but that is a nasty workaround as it demands duplication of many cells. I would rather like a solution that will allow to do that in google script itself.

Comment: OK, it seems that the API for Date in a JavaScript one. However I still did not manage to sum in Google Script two cells with values like 36:12:00 and 71:34:00 and get a meaningful result. Doing that in spreadsheet is working fine.

Comment: Sounds like a javascript question - Google Script is Javascript

Comment: After more investigation I think the problem is not in Java Script API but the fact that Google uses Date() for "Hours" format. In debugger I saw something like that `new Date(-2209045440000)` created automatically for a cell with value `33:40:00`.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object ... the value Date(2209045440000) is in milliseconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a working function that does the trick.

I first tried to format it as a date but 36 hours is not really standard !! so I did a little bit of math :-) )

To get it working you should set a cell somewhere with value `00:00:00` that we will use as a reference date in spreadsheet standard. in my code it is cell `D1`(see comment in code, reference date in SS is in 1900 and in Javascript is in 1970 ... that's why it is a negative constant of 70 years in milliseconds...)

here is the code and below a screen capture of the test sheet + the logger
It would be a good idea to modify this code to make it a function that takes cell value as parameter and returns the result as an array for example ([h,m,s] or something similar), this code is only to show how it works.

```
function addHoursValues() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var hours1 = sh.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var hours2 = sh.getRange('B1').getValue();
  var ref = sh.getRange('D1').getValue().getTime();
//var ref = -2209161600000 // you could also use this but it would be less obvious what it really does ;-)
Logger.log(ref+' = ref');
  var h1 = parseInt((hours1.getTime()/3600000)-ref/3600000);
  var h2 = parseInt((hours2.getTime()/3600000)-ref/3600000);
Logger.log(h1+' + '+h2+' = '+(h1+h2))
  var m1 = parseInt((hours1.getTime()-h1*3600000-ref)/60000);
  var m2 = parseInt((hours2.getTime()-h2*3600000-ref)/60000);
Logger.log(m1+' + '+m2+' = '+(m1+m2))
  var s1 = parseInt((hours1.getTime()-h1*3600000-m1*60000-ref)/1000);
  var s2 = parseInt((hours2.getTime()-h2*3600000-m2*60000-ref)/1000);
Logger.log(s1+' + '+s2+' = '+(s1+s2))
  var ts=s1+s2
  var tm=m1+m2
  var th=h1+h2
    if(ts>59){ts=ts-60;tm++};
    if(tm>59){tm=tm-60;th++}
Logger.log('sum = '+th+':'+tm+':'+ts)
}
```

[image]

[image]

---

**EDIT :** here are 2 "function" versions with corresponding test functions that show how to use it

```
function getHMS(hrs) {
  var t = hrs.getTime()/1000;
  var ref = -2209161600;
  var h = parseInt((t-ref)/3600);
  var m = parseInt((t-h*3600-ref)/60);
  var s = parseInt(t-h*3600-m*60-ref);
  return[h,m,s];// returns an array of 3 discrete values
}

function testHMS(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var hours1 = sh.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var hours2 = sh.getRange('B1').getValue();

  var sumS = getHMS(hours1)[2]+getHMS(hours2)[2];// add seconds
  var sumM = getHMS(hours1)[1]+getHMS(hours2)[1];// add minutes
  var sumH = getHMS(hours1)[0]+getHMS(hours2)[0];// add hours
    if(sumS>59){sumS=sumS-60 ; sumM++}; // handles values >59
    if(sumM>59){sumM=sumM-60 ; sumH++}; // handles values >59
  Logger.log(sumH+':'+sumM+':'+sumS);
}
```

OR

```
function addHMS(hrs1,hrs2) {
  var t1 = hrs1.getTime()/1000;
  var t2 = hrs2.getTime()/1000;
  var ref = -2209161600;
  var h = parseInt((t1-ref)/3600)+parseInt((t2-ref)/3600);
  var m = parseInt((t1-parseInt((t1-ref)/3600)*3600-ref)/60)+parseInt((t2-parseInt((t2-ref)/3600)*3600-ref)/60);
  var s = parseInt(t1-parseInt((t1-ref)/3600)*3600-parseInt((t1-parseInt((t1-ref)/3600)*3600-ref)/60)*60-ref)
         +parseInt(t2-parseInt((t2-ref)/3600)*3600-parseInt((t2-parseInt((t2-ref)/3600)*3600-ref)/60)*60-ref);
    if(s>59){s=s-60 ; m++}; // handles values >59
    if(m>59){m=m-60 ; h++}; // handles values >59
  return[h,m,s];// returns sum in an array of 3 discrete values
}

function othertestHMS(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var hours1 = sh.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var hours2 = sh.getRange('B1').getValue();
  Logger.log(addHMS(hours1,hours2));
}
```