# Modal boostrap compare 2 date

Tags: javascript, php

I am beginner using bootstrap PDO and php. javascript
How can I compare 2 date like image below.

[image]

Comment: You're going to have to narrow down where you want to compare it. Bootstrap is mostly for CSS, so ignore that. If you want to alert the user immediately, then you'll need javascript. If you want to compare it after the form is submitted, then you'll need PHP. There are already a lot of answers on SO on how to compare dates in both languages.

Comment: It would also be nice to know how you want to compare the dates. If you don't understand what I mean you could, instead, say **why** you want to compare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depens on when/where u want to compare them. While filling out the form will require JS/Jquery. After submitting requires PHP.

In **PHP** it should work like this:

```
$date1 = "2022-02-02";
$date2 = "2021-01-01";
$dateTime1 = strtotime($date1);
$dateTime2 = strtotime($date2);

if ($dateTime1 > $dateTime2){
   echo "$date1 is latest than $date2";
}else{
   echo "$date1 is older than $date2";
}
```

PHP manual [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php).

For **JQuery** use [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743013/compare-date-time-in-jquery).

Comment: Thank... Does it work in modal boostrap window ?

Comment: Otherwise I made this code for modal when I tryu to ADD New record and it work fine.

Comment: Sorry for late response, but yes, it should work there aswell.