# Add an hour to time and then return formatted

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
//console.log(response.data[key]) = 12:40
newDateObj = new Date(today + ' '+ response.data[key]);
console.log(newDateObj);
//Mon Apr 30 2001 12:40:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
newDateObjAltered = (newDateObj.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 1000));  
console.log(newDateObjAltered);
//988634400000
```

All I want to do is take the time stored in response.data[key] and add an hour to it and then return it in the same format. So for the example above I'd want 13:40 back. I'm getting the timestamp back...how can I format this correctly?

Comment: you can try this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newDateObjAltered = new Date(newDateObj.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 1000));
```