# Set a cookie expire after 3 hours

Tags: javascript, cookies

Set a cookie expire after 3 hours

I have this JavaScript code:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*2*60*60*1000));        
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
```

How can I make the cookie expire after 3 hours?

Comment: the code is misleading ... that cookie would expire `days * 2 hours` - so, calling the function like `createCookie("blah", "fred", 1.5) would do it

Comment: change `days*2*60*60*1000` to `days*24*60*60*1000` and then call the function as createCookie('name', 'value',0.125).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set a cookie expire after 2 hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068812/set-a-cookie-expire-after-2-hours)

Answer (score 0):

**1st Method**

Modify function to be:

```
function createCookie(name,value,hours) {
    if (hours) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(hours*60*60*1000));        
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";}
```

And you will use `createCookie(...,...,3);`

**2nd Method**

Or using the following prototype:

```
Date.prototype.addHours= function(h){
    this.setHours(this.getHours()+h);
    return this;
}
```

And the following createCookie function:

```
  function createCookie(name,value,date) {
        if(date){
            var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";}
```

And you will use `createCookie(...,...,new Date().addHours(3));`

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to save the cookie for only 1/12 of a day.

```
days*2*60*60*1000
```

should be

```
days*24*60*60*1000
```

So when you want 3 hours you need to save the cookie for 1/8 of a day `24/8`

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));        
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

createCookie("name", "3 hours", 1/8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it should be like this

```
function createCookie(name,value,hours) {
if (hours) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(hours*60*60*1000));        
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";}
```