# Change day in a function used by onclick, javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hey there i have the following problem. I am sure you could help me:

I have a button that change the hour +1 hour or - 1 hour. But the date jumps from 00UTC to 23 UTC on the same day and not the day before.

Note: addZero completes the string from 1 to "01" (it is because an image string needs 01 02 03 )

```
function switch_image(i) {
  if (i == 0) {
    d.setUTCHours(d.getUTCHours() - 1);

    if (d.getUTCHours() == 23) {
      d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() - 1);
    }
    h = addZero(d.getUTCHours());

  } else {
    d.setUTCHours(d.getUTCHours() + 1);

    if (d.getUTCHours() == 0) {
      d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 1);
    }
    h = addZero(d.getUTCHours());
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding hours to Javascript Date object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself. I forgot to set the variable for days (it s t, for hpurs its h) new. Best regards .

Answer (score 0):

See the following function which adds a constant value to another date using `Date.UTC(1970,0,1)` as a starting value (Jan 1, 1970 is [the Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)). Note that months and years aren't included because they aren't constant times (there are leap years and months don't span the same number of days).

```js
Date.prototype.addTime = function(days,hours,minutes,seconds,milliseconds){
  for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
    arguments[i]=parseInt(arguments[i]);
  }
  return new Date(this.getTime() +
      Date.UTC(1970, 0,
          (isNaN(days) ? 0 : days) + 1,
          isNaN(hours) ? 0 : hours,
          isNaN(minutes) ? 0 : minutes,
          isNaN(seconds) ? 0 : seconds,
          isNaN(milliseconds) ? 0 : milliseconds));
}
document.body.innerHTML = new Date(Date.now()).addTime(1,1).toString(); //Adds 1 day,1 hour
```

---

**Reference:** [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)