# Converting String value to Date and adding 200 minutes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have string date value returned from database. `Date is ="2015-06-26 13:23:04"`.
How to `add 200 minutes` to this in javascript?
I am not able to convert it to Date. I want same format.

I want to dispaly the same format "2015-06-26 13:23:04".

I used below code to convert.

```
 var datevar = "2015-06-26 13:23:04";
 var today = new Date(datevar).toISOString().slice(0, 20);
```

and i cant get correct hh:mm:ss value.

getting : `"2015-06-26TO7:53:04"`

Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: There are many questions about manipulating time in all coding languages. I suggest you do some serious research before asking questions. You may also want to read the [how to ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn about what should be included in a good question such as an attempt.

Comment: I searched. I tried those solutions. but i didn't get any help. So i asked

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding hours to Javascript Date object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object)

Comment: @IMRUP Searching your exact title showed solutions, so I would suggest that you research more thoroughly.

Comment: Format is the problem. I cant get the same format. "2015-06-26 13:23:04". after adding also same format

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure your string is like that, you can transform it into milliseconds and then add 20*60*1000 which corresponds to 20minuts

```js
var yourString= "2015-06-26 13:23:04",
     year=yourString.substring(0,4),
     month=yourString.substring(5,7),
     day=yourString.substring(8,10),
     hour=yourString.substring(11,13),
     minuts=yourString.substring(14,16),
     secondes=yourString.substring(17,19),
     mkdate= new Date(year,month,day,hour,minuts,secondes),
     add200Minutes =mkdate.getTime() + 200*60*1000,
     newDate=new Date(add200Minutes);

     alert(newDate);
```