# How to add hours to the given date using jquery?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a date 2015-7-15 and I want to add 9 hours to the given date I am trying but not getting result please help me.

Comment: what did you try....  how did you get the above value

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding hours to Javascript Date object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object)

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".start_date, .end_date").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'}); 
});

Comment: This is a simple task which you should know how to research yourself. Even typing your question in to google gets you the answer.

Comment: this is what I have done to get date value in the above format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your answer by googling.

```
var myDate = new Date();
```

OR if you have the date, month and year, create a date as

```
var myDate = new Date(year, month, date);
```

then you can add the hours to your date

```
myDate.setHours(myDate.getHours()+h);
```

will do that

Comment: function setEndDate(k)
  {
   alert(k);
    
    var date2 = $('#startdate'+k).val(); 
    //date2.setHours(date2.getHours()+15); 
    
    
    date2.AddHours(24);
    alert(date2);
    $('#enddate'+k).val(date2);
    
  }

Comment: What is k here? if k = 1, Do you have a field with ID = startdate1 ?

Comment: @Dipak-user3085702 you didn't convert `date2` to date object try this:`function setEndDate(k) {
  
    var date2 = new Date($('#startdate' + k).val());
    date2.setHours(date2.getHours() + 15);
    alert(date2);
    $('#enddate' + k).val(date2);
}`

Answer (score 2):

I created this function:

```
Date.prototype.addHours(h) {
   this.setHours(this.getHours() + h);
   return this;
}
```

and I called

```
alert(new Date().addHours(5));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes()+ add 9 hour in minutes);
```

And I suggest to use time in UNIX time stamp.