# setHours() convert my Date object in string timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

I try to set a date to midnight to simplify my date manipulation, for this I wrote this part of code:

```
var now = new Date();
today = now.setHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(now, today);
```

I'm surprised to see `now` contains a Date object and `today` a timestamp. This brings errors when I want to use getMonth() or other date's functions. It's paintful to recreate a Date object with the timestamp.

Is it normal? How can I fix this?

(Feel free to update my post to correct my bad english :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object is smiliar but  doesn't provide answer.

Comment: Why not just use the `now` objected you created?

Comment: So what is the actual question? What exactly you want to fix? How an objective answer can be given to a question "is it normal" unless one is a psychiatrist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Is it normal?***

Yes

***How can I fix this?***

You are assigning the return value of `now.setHours(0,0,0,0)`to `today`.

Maybe what you are looking for is something like this:

```
var now = new Date();

var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

In this way, `setHours` is acting upon the value you wish to have the hours set on. This is the primary manner of using `setHours`.

***Other details***

- The [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours#Using_setHours()) doesn't appear to mention the return value. Other sites such as w3schools do.
- The [Chromium setHours source](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/v8/src/js/date.js&q=SET_LOCAL_DATE_VALUE&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=572) shows a value being return though [other functions](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/v8/src/js/date.js&q=SET_LOCAL_DATE_VALUE&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=185) that perform similarly do not return this value. I presume that the `SET_LOCAL_DATE_VALUE` function found in chromium's date.js is assigning the value into the first argument.

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools. There is the [*language specification*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) as the normative reference and [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) for examples.

Comment: Thank you. I understand my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar situation and pcnate answer didn't solved my issue...
What I did was:

```
var today = new Date();
today = new Date(today.setHours(0,0,0,0));
console.log('Date: '+today);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate dates easily using [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) or [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

date.js:

```
   Date.today().set({ hour : 0 });
```

moment.js

```
   moment().set({ "hour": 0, "minute" : 0, "second": 0});
```