# How to add 2hrs to current DateTime and display result back as DateTime

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am using the following in JS to find current Date Time -

```
var now = new Date();
now = now.format("dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm tt");
```

Now I want to calculate by adding 2hrs to current instance of 'now'

```
 var now = new Date();
 var departureTime = new Date(now);
 departureTime = departureTime.setHours(now.getHours() + 2);
 now = now.format("dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm tt");
 departureTime = departureTime.format("dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm tt");
```

However the formatting of departureTime is not correct... How can I add 2hrs to the current time and then display my result back as 1/28/2016 7:30 PM?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding hours to Javascript Date object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object)

Comment: no that is not answered

Comment: `format()` is not a method of `Date` by default.  Are you using a specific library?

Comment: working with html5 and AngularJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add 2 hours like this:

```js
var now = new Date();
var d = new Date(now.getTime() + 2*60*60*1000);
// 1/28/2016 7:30 PM
var formattedDeparture = (d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + d.getDate()
   + "/" + d.getFullYear() + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();
alert(now + " +2 hours is " + formattedDeparture);
```

This will format it with 24 hours, if you really need AM/PM, look at: [How do you display javascript datetime in 12 hour AM/PM format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format)
To format dateTime in different ways you can use this answer: [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)