# Add hours to a DateTime

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to add 1.5 hours to a datetime :

```
var date = new Date('08/18/2016 19:00:00');

date.setHours(date.getHours() + 1.5);
```

Expected result :

```
date = 08/18/2016 20:30:00;
```

But I have :

```
date = 08/18/2016 20:00:00;
```

Why and how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding hours to Javascript Date object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object)

Comment: @MehdiDehghani: Except that question and its answers are for whole hours, not fractional hours.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours : `An **integer** between 0 and 23, representing the hour.` So, with all due respect, RTFM.

Answer (score 4):

> Why?

Because `setHours` doesn't accept fractional values. If you [follow through the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.sethours), you'll find it runs the hours value through the abstract [`ToInteger`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-tointeger) operation, which chops off the `.5`.

> how to do this?

`setHours` actually accepts minutes (and seconds and such) as additional arguments:

```
date.setHours(date.getHours() + 1, date.getMinutes() + 30);
```

Alternately, you can do them separately:

```
date.setHours(date.getHours() + 1);
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 30);
```

Or as milliseconds:

```
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1.5 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```