# How to add 24hr in current unix timestamp in NodeJs or in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to add 24 hours to the unix timestamp for now in **nodejs or in javascript**. I also would like to know is there is any direct function or property in Date DOM object. 
I found the relevent function in PHP. This code will returns new unix time after adding 24hrs in current unix timestamp.

```
$currentUnixTime=time();
$newUnixTime=strtotime('+1 day', $currentUnixTime);
return newUnixTime;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding hours to Javascript Date object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object)

Comment: If you need to more lots of date manipulations momentjs is highly recommended

Answer (score 3):

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setHours(myDate.getHours()+24);
return myDate;
```

Comment: this one is much better than the other one

Comment: Thanks for reply,
I run the above code and i got the output as follows
    

    Fri Oct 28 2016 17:23:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
    Sat Oct 29 2016 17:23:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

But here i have to convert this string time to unix timestamp again. And this will increase my little more processing time. Is there is any direct function where i will enter only the added extra time (current unixtime+24hr) and it will return me the final answer in unix timestamp.

    $newUnixTime=functionName('+1 day', Date.now());

Comment: There's no such thing like '+1 day' in standard javascript library. You can use external libraries like momentjs.com to be able to do moment().add(1, 'days')

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to add one day, you should use momentjs library, which is available both for frontent and nodejs.

```
var now = new Date()
var tomorrow = moment(now).add(1, 'day');
```

This is more robust than adding 24 hours because it takes into account DST changes. For that sole reason you should avoid direct `Date` manipulation in JS in most of the cases.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

> Special considerations for months and years
>
> If the day of the month on the original date is greater than the
>   number of days in the final month, the day of the month will change to
>   the last day in the final month.
>
> ```
> moment([2010, 0, 31]);                  // January 31
> moment([2010, 0, 31]).add(1, 'months'); // February 28
> ```
>
> There are also special considerations to keep in mind when adding time
>   that crosses over daylight saving time. If you are adding years,
>   months, weeks, or days, the original hour will always match the added
>   hour.
>
> ```
> var m = moment(new Date(2011, 2, 12, 5, 0, 0)); // the day before DST in the US m.hours(); // 5 
> m.add(1, 'days').hours(); // 5
> ```
>
> If you are adding hours, minutes, seconds, or milliseconds, the
>   assumption is that you want precision to the hour, and will result in
>   a different hour.
>
> ```
> var m = moment(new Date(2011, 2, 12, 5, 0, 0)); // the day before DST in the US m.hours(); // 5
> m.add(24, 'hours').hours(); // 6
> ```