# Subtract time from the users select value using Java Script

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if there is a way to subtract the time from the users selection by a few hours. In other words if the user selects 1:00 **AM** the result will be 11:00 **PM**. I start doing it, but I got stuck...

```js
function myFunction() {
  var hour = document.getElementById("selectHour").value;
  var minute = document.getElementById("selectMinute").value;
  var ampm = document.getElementById("selectAMPM").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = hour + ":" + minute + " " + ampm;
}
```

```html
<select id="selectHour">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
</select>

<select id="selectMinute">
  <option value="00">00</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="35">35</option>
  <option value="40">40</option>
  <option value="45">45</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="55">55</option>
</select>

<select id="selectAMPM">
    <option value="am">am</option>
    <option value="pm">pm</option>
</select>
  
<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding hours to Javascript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object)

Comment: What did you try? Your `myFunction` does not compute anything... Anyway, you could be interested in the `Date` object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and the moment.js library (https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using this

```
var dateTime = this.setTime(this.getTime() + (h*60*60*1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by converting your time in 24 hour format and then handle logic for am/pm separately. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ae1afbpm/1/)

```
    function myFunction() {
  var hour = document.getElementById("selectHour").value;
  var minute = document.getElementById("selectMinute").value;
  var ampm = document.getElementById("selectAMPM").value;

    var hourin24hourformat = hour;

  if(ampm === 'pm'){
        hourin24hourformat = (+hourin24hourformat)+12;
    }
  hourin24hourformat = hourin24hourformat-2;

     ampm='am';
    if(hourin24hourformat==0){ //At 00 hours we need to show 12 am
    hourin24hourformat=12;
    }
    else if(hourin24hourformat>12)
    {
    hourin24hourformat=hourin24hourformat%12;
    ampm='pm';
    }else if(hourin24hourformat === 12){
     ampm='pm';
    }

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = hourin24hourformat + ":" + minute + " " + ampm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this It works**

```js
function myFunction() {
    var hour = document.getElementById("selectHour").value;
    var minute = document.getElementById("selectMinute").value;
    var ampm = document.getElementById("selectAMPM").value;
    hour = parseInt(hour);
    if(hour<12 && ampm=='am')
    {
      hour=hour+12-2;
      if(hour==12)
      {
        ampm='am';
      }
      else if(hour>12)
      {
        hour=hour-12;
        ampm='am';
      }
      else{
      ampm='pm';
    }
  }
    else if(hour<12 && ampm=='pm'){
      hour=hour+12-2;
      if(hour==12)
      {
        ampm='pm';
      }
      else if(hour>12)
      {
        hour=hour-12;
        ampm='pm';
      }
      else{
      ampm='am';
    }
  }
    else if(hour==12 && ampm=='am')
    {
      hour=hour-2;
      ampm='pm';
    }
    else if(hour==12 && ampm=='pm')
    {
      hour=hour-2;
      ampm='am';
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = hour + ":" + minute + " " + ampm;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<select id="selectHour">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
</select>

<select id="selectMinute">
  <option value="00">00</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="35">35</option>
  <option value="40">40</option>
  <option value="45">45</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="55">55</option>
</select>

<select id="selectAMPM">
    <option value="am">am</option>
    <option value="pm">pm</option>
</select>
  
<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>

<p id="result"></p> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Kamala, thank you so much for showing me this method! However if for example I want to subtract  1 hour and 35 minuts? It does not seem to work. Again thank you so much in advance!