# Past 2hours date and Time in IST Format javascript

Tags: javascript

I know that

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var currentOffset = currentTime.toISOString();
```

will give current date & time in IST format. Can anyone help me how to get past 2 hours date & time in IST format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding hours to Javascript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate a time difference, you can use a combination of [the relevant `get` and `set` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). After you get the value, you perform the desired calculation and use the result as the argument for the set.

Note that the default timezone is based on system settings. So performing such a change has no bearing on the timezone (i.e. for me the code outputs in PDT).

```js
var time = new Date();
var currentOffset = time.getTimezoneOffset();

console.log('Current time: ' + time.toISOString());
console.log('Current offset: ' + currentOffset);

time.setHours(time.getHours() - 2);
var pastOffset = time.getTimezoneOffset();

console.log('Past time: ' + time.toISOString());
console.log('Past offset: ' + currentOffset);
```

Comment: But I need time stamp in ISO Format

Comment: Then you just use [Date.prototype.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString). Updated example in answer.