# Adding hours to an existing date and gain the new date through JS

Tags: javascript, date

I have a javascript function which add a certain amount of hours to a provided date and return the new date as follows.

```
$scope.CalDate = function()
{
var preDate = "2019-06-20 21:30";
var formatDate = new Date(preDate );
var diffHours = 2.30;
var newDate = new Date(formatDate.getTime() + (diffHours*1000*60*60));
return newDate;
}
```

Actual answer should be **Wed Jun 21 2019 00:00:00**. But it returns the following answer. **Thu Jun 20 2019 23:48:00**. Why is it happening ?

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object

Comment: It's because you're adding 2.3 hours, not 2 and a half. Your diff would have to be 2.5

Comment: See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) Also `new Date("2019-06-20 21:30")` returns an invalid date in some implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the hours and minutes to a date following method was used.

```
$scope.CalDate = function()
{
var preDate = "2019-06-20 21:30";
var formatDate = new Date(preDate );
var diffHours = 2.3;
formatDate.setHours(formatDate.getHours() + 2);
formateDate.setMinutes(formatDate.getMinutes() + 30);
return formateDate;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are adding 2.3 hours instead of 2.5 hours(2 and a half)

```
$scope.CalDate = function()
{
var preDate = "2019-06-20 21:30";
var formatDate = new Date(preDate );
var diffHours = 2.5;//Add 2 and a half hours
var newDate = new Date(formatDate.getTime() + (diffHours*1000*60*60));
return newDate;
}
```

To convert 2.3 to the correct multiplier, use `Math.floor(2.3) + (2.3%1)/0.6`

```
$scope.CalDate = function()
{
var preDate = "2019-06-20 21:30";
var formatDate = new Date(preDate );
var diffHours = 2.3;
var actualDiff = Math.floor(diffHours) + (diffHours % 1)/0.6


var newDate = new Date(formatDate.getTime() + (actualDiff*1000*60*60));
return newDate;
}
```

Comment: Im getting the diffHours by using hours and minutes. Therefore it gives as 2.3. What shall I do?

Comment: @tharindu you can simply multiple it proportionately?

Comment: Math.floor(2.3) + (2.3%1)/0.6 - replace 2.3 with the variable where you store

Comment: Note that Javascript floating point calculations [*aren't always accurate*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), so using decimal hours in stead of hrs, mins, secs may produce minor errors that give annoyingly inaccurate results. If `"2.3"` should be `"2:30"` then treat it as such, don't convert it to `2.5` and hope things are OK.

Comment: Its correct @tharindu It translates to 2.499 which is close enough to 2.5. If you're using a literal 2.3 change it to 2.5. If you are calculating the 2.3, please post code on how you're getting to that number