# How can I substract hours from my date using data from a string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a date in UTC in javascript, and I would like to substract some hours.

I searched online and apparently I should concat the substraction to the date like the following:

```
const diff = "-5"
const utcDate = "2017-02-22 17:28:13"
const date = new Date(utcDate + diff[0] + ' ' + diff[1])
//desired output: 2017-02-22 12:28:13
```

But I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1050782/5202550).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do all my Date calculations with `.getTime()`.
So an hour is 3600000 milliseconds.

```js
const MILLISECONDS_HOUR = 3600000;

const diff = -5;
const utcDate_str = "2017-02-22 17:28:13";

const utcDate = new Date( utcDate_str );

const minus_5_hours = new Date( utcDate.getTime() + ( MILLISECONDS_HOUR * diff ));

console.log( utcDate.toJSON());
console.log( minus_5_hours.toJSON());
```

The big advantage is that javascript will take care of leap years, month boundaries and such.

But since you are calling your variable `diff`, are you trying to calculate lcoal time vs UTC time?

In that case, reread the javascript Date methods. There's a bunch of methods to handle both UTC and local time, for example: `date.getUTCDate()` and `date.getDate()`.

So you might not have to calculate all of this yourself.

Also, if you format your dates according to the ISO, `"2017-02-22T17:28:13.000Z"`, this will automatically get parsed as UTC.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
someDate.setHours(someDate.getHours()+1);
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/1050782/537998