# Operations with Date object js

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

How can I do mathematical operations with Date using just vanilla JS ?

something like : today + 2 days

```
const today = new Date(27/3/2020);
const DayToAdd = 2;


return today + DaytoAdd
//expected 29/3/2020
```

Comment: what's your goal?

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan Why is that important?

Comment: There is a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object