# JavaScript: Add half an hour to a Locale Time String

Tags: javascript, datetime

I´m trying to create a code that adds some time (let´s say half an hour) to the current time.
I could withdraw current time, but struggle to add the time to it. This is how the code looks so far:

```
<script>
var dt = new Date();
document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleTimeString('en', {hour: 'numeric',minute: 'numeric',});

</script>
```

What could be the possible solution?
I am very new to this, so every input is appreciated!

Comment: Please only use tags relevant to the question (Java != JavaScript).

Comment: Possibly related/duplicate: [How to add 30 minutes to a JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add 30 minutes to a JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding hours to JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object)

Answer (score 1):

You could add `30` to the `minutes` part of a Date.

```
var time = new Date();
time.setMinutes(time.getMinutes() + 30);
```

This will work correctly in recent versions of NodeJS. Even for adding more minutes than in an hour. e.g. `+ 120` minutes. However, it is unclear if every implementation of JavaScript will behave the same here. It might be possible for an implementation to just update minutes (and not hours) *e.g.* 08:48 + 30 might become 08:18 instead of 09:18

Comment: "*However, it is unclear if every implementation of JavaScript will behave the same \[when adding more than 60 minutes\]*" actually it's very clear, per [ECMA-262](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.setminutes). Any implementation compliant with the standard will allow setting the minutes to any valid number value and will adjust the internal *time value* accordingly.