# How to add one hour for "24 hours" Time format in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to add one hour in **24 hours** time format using Javascript or JQuery.

like

if 23:00 then it should be 00:00 
if 11:00 then 12:00 
if 13:00 then 14:00
if 09:00 then 10:00

for that I tried below code. That's perfectly works

```
    function increase24TimeByOne(timeStr) {
            var splitedTimeStr = timeStr.split(':');
            var hours = parseInt(splitedTimeStr[0]);
            var minutes = splitedTimeStr[1].substring(0, 2);
            var nextHours = (hours + 1);
          
            if(nextHours.toString().length == 1){
                nextHours = "0" + nextHours;
            }
            if(nextHours == 24){
                nextHours = "00"
            }
            return nextHours + ":" + minutes;
        }
```

but I want to know that code is better or not ? 
Can anyone please suggest ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding hours to JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object)

Comment: maths ... `var nextHours = (hours + 1) % 24;` or betterer ... `var nextHours = ((hours + 1) % 24).toString().padStart(2, '0');` ... bang! wrap the time AND add leading zero in one line of code

Comment: @VladReshetilo that answer is for a Date object - OP has a string.  Maybe they could convert to a date object first, but seems overkill.

Comment: @Bravo betterer???  :)  Would your comment be betterer as an upvotable answer?

Comment: @freedomn-m Date object is not overkill, it's the correct way for manipulating with date. Manual manipulation with seconds/hours/etc is a bad practice

Comment: @freedomn-m I would upvote that betterer answer

Comment: @freedomn-m - working on it

Comment: @VladReshetilo debatable (but not here) - but OP isn't manipulating a date - they only have the time, as a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using modulo maths add 1 modulo 24

i.e. `(23 + 1) % 24 === 0`

```js
function increase24TimeByOne(timeStr) {
  var splitedTimeStr = timeStr.split(':');
  var hours = parseInt(splitedTimeStr[0]);
  var minutes = splitedTimeStr[1].substring(0, 2);
  var nextHours = (hours + 1) % 24;
  var nextMeridiem;
  if (nextHours.toString().length == 1) {
    nextHours = "0" + nextHours;
  }
  return nextHours + ":" + minutes;
}

console.log(increase24TimeByOne('23:45'))
```

You can do better, by converting to string AND padding (optionally) the '0' at the same time

using `toString().padStart(2, '0')` - i.e add '0' until the string is at least 2 in length

```js
function increase24TimeByOne(timeStr) {
    var splitedTimeStr = timeStr.split(':');
    var hours = parseInt(splitedTimeStr[0]);
    var minutes = splitedTimeStr[1].substring(0, 2);
    var nextHours = ((hours + 1) % 24).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    return nextHours + ":" + minutes;
}
console.log(increase24TimeByOne('23:45'))
```

In my opinion, you can do this with even less code by using string templates

It may not be so readable though, but less code is better code (to a point)

```js
function increase24TimeByOne(timeStr) {
    let [hours, minutes] = timeStr.split(':');
    return `${((+hours + 1) % 24).toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${minutes}`;
}
console.log(increase24TimeByOne('23:45'))
```

Comment: @freedomn-m - don't worry, I'll make it Engllisher now :p

Comment: @freedomn-m - I should've made the last code the "betterest" :p

Comment: @Bravo Thank you for suggestion. Second one is better for me. Third one is not working because of "let". I have tried "var" but not worked Sorry I'm new in this so I don't know which keyword I need to use. Can you please inform me which keyword should I use instead of "let or var"?

Comment: @M123 - what javascript engine doesn't have let? internet explorer 7?

Comment: @Bravo FireFox, Actually I have used this code in .jsp file so if I use "let" then give me error like "org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "+" "+ "" at line 1, column 5." and  on let keyword give me error like "Syntax error on token "var", delete this token"

Comment: @M123 - I can assure you `firefox` can run the last code - I wonder if it's the typo where I forgot a space ... hang on ... added a space after `let` - maybe whatever is having the issue will be fine now - but, I confess, no idea what this `.jsp file` refers to - nothing to do with firefox browser

Comment: @M123 does the snippet provided here work for you?

Comment: Just use what works @M123 - no need to wonder why some random javascript engine doesn't work with modern code

Comment: @Bravo I tried `let` with space but still getting same  error so I think `.jsp file` can't take it. FYI we can use `.jsp file`  for making web pages in Java.

Comment: @M123 oh, java ... god speed :p

Comment: @Bravo Yeah second one.  I have reduced second one like `function increase24TimeByOne1(timeStr) {
      var splitedTimeStr = timeStr.split(':');
      var hours = parseInt(splitedTimeStr[0]);
      return ((hours + 1) % 24).toString().padStart(2, '0') + ":" + splitedTimeStr[1];
  }`