# Convert string to time and add 2 hours in JS

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, html-framework-7

i get this time from an external JSON :

`"time":"19:45"`
I need to add 2 hours from this string. 
Is it possible in JS?
Thanks

Comment: Is this possible in any language?, time does not exist without being a part of the date,   if  you mean this is today's time, then it will make some sense.

Comment: sure it does @vaira, every day has a 7 o'clock and 2 hours later it's 9

Comment: what about `23:01`? it will become `01:01`?

Comment: is it "time":"09:24" or "time:":"9:14"? Do you have a leading zero or not?

Comment: @pilchard the question is '"convert" string to time and add 2 hours in JS', I did not think he was asking for just sting manipulation

Comment: That's a fair point @vaira (and there are moments when adding 2 hours isn't as straight forward as I made out, depending on the date)

Comment: yes, you should convert data from JSON to Js and add 2 hours after that again convert JS to JSON. you can add hours like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
let myTime = '19:45'

function getTime(time, addHour) {
  let [h, m] = time.split(':');
  let date = new Date();
   date.setHours(h, m, 0)
   date.toString();
  let res = `${date.getHours()+addHour}:${date.getMinutes()}`
  return res
}
 
console.log(getTime( myTime, 2 ))
```

Comment: You're adding outside of the Date object, so this won't switch over at midnight

Answer (score 0):

uses `String.split` to get `hourNum` and `minuteNum`, then construct one `Date` object and uses `setTime` to add two hours.

```js
function addHours(text, hours=2) {
  const [hourNum, minNum] = text.split(':')
  const time = new Date(0, 0, 0, hourNum, minNum)
  time.setTime(time.getTime() + (hours * 60 * 60 * 1000))
  return `${time.getHours()}:${time.getMinutes()}`
}

console.log(addHours('19:45', 2))
console.log(addHours('23:45', 2))
```

Comment: This may have trouble with changing offsets, `new Date(0,0,0)` actually creates a Date for 1899-12-31 around which time many places changed their offset so the increment may push the time from one offset to another, causing the resulting time to be unexpected. Consider using UTC instead. :-) Why is year 0 treated as 1900? It's an ECMASCript Date object of course! Years 0 to 99 are treated as 1900 to 1999.

Answer (score 0):

A Date object isn't necessary to do time mathematics, it just means taking account of minutes and seconds (60) and maybe days (24).

E.g.

```js
// Add time to a timestamp, both in in HH:mm format
// If respectDay is true, hours are % 24
function addTime(start, increment, respectDay = false) {
  let pad = n => ('0' + n).slice(-2);
  let timeToMins = time => time.split(':').reduce((h, m) => h*60 + m*1);
  let minsToTime = (mins, respectDay = false) => `${pad((mins / 60 | 0) % (respectDay? 24 : Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY))}:${pad(mins%60)}`;
  return minsToTime(timeToMins(start) + timeToMins(increment), respectDay);
}

let time = "19:45";
console.log(addTime(time, '8:23'));       // Total time  : 28:08
console.log(addTime(time, '8:23', true)); // As day time : 04:08
```