# Reduce Hours in a Javascript DateTime String

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the database the timetable comes in the right format

```
2022-04-26T08:15:08.000Z
```

When I use node to select, the time is

```
2022-04-26T11:15:08.000Z
```

On the front end I tried

```
hours.setHours(hours.getHours() - 3);
```

but it did not work, Show me this

```
horas.getHours is not a function
```

I need to change the time from

```
"2022-04-26T11:15:08.000Z"
```

to

```
 "2022-04-26T08:15:08.000Z",
```

If possible to create a function that removes 3 hours, it would be better

Comment: Something like that should work. Can you show us more of the code.

Comment: "but it did not work" - how did it not work? (Did you allow for the fact that the console will translate the date to your machine's time zone?)

Comment: I will edit my question @phuzi

Comment: `let now = new Date(); console.log(now); now.setHours(now.getHours() - 3); console.log(now);` shows the time changes to 3 hours before. Something about the "hours" variable may be incorrect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add hours to a Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/how-to-add-hours-to-a-date-object)

Comment: Looks like you need to parse the ISO 8601 formatted string in to an actual Date object first.

Comment: Could you show me how to do this?

Comment: Why not take a look at [the documentation for Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: my solution at the moment is  "function FornatarHoras(horas) {

    let hours = horas.substring(11,13)
    let diminuirHoras = hours - 3;
    let minutes = horas.substring(14,16)
    let dateFormated = `${diminuirHoras}:${minutes}`
    
      return dateFormated
   }", but but i don't think this is correct

Comment: Maybe you should also wonder why there's a 3 hours difference between frontend and backed. Maybe timezone? Manual manipulations on timezones may be dangerous

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your date to timestamp and create a new one with the timestamp with 3 hours removed

```
const date = new Date()
const timestamp = date.getTime() - 3 * 3600 * 1000
const newDate = new Date(timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
horas.getHours is not a function
```

Maybe `horas` is a plain string? In that case,

```
const hours = new Date(horas);
hours.setHours(hours.getHours() - 3);
// and maybe format it back to a string, if needed
```

should work. Otherwise, what *is* `horas`?

Answer (score 0):

transform to miliseconds than get the date in different formats

```js
console.log(new Date(new Date().getTime() - 10800000).toISOString())
console.log(new Date(new Date().getTime() - 10800000).toUTCString())
console.log(new Date(new Date().getTime() - 10800000).toLocaleString())
```